# Offscreen toggle menu pushes main content off right side of screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggleclass

Hello and thanks for your time.  The following HTML, CSS, and JavaScript serves to create an off-screen menu that toggles into view upon clicking the anchor.  The main content of the page is then sent off-screen on the right.  Is there a way to make the main content wrap or resize to stay fully visible on the screen when the off-screen menu pushes it to the right?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.toggle-nav').click(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('show-nav');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  width: 700px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.site-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.push-wrap {
  border: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease 0;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease 0;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease 0;
  transition: all 300ms ease 0;

  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);

  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.show-nav .push-wrap {
  border: 1px solid green;
  transform: translate(700px, 0); 
  transform: translate3d(700px, 0, 0);
}

body {
  background: #e3e3e3;
}

a {
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

nav {
  background: #2b343f;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1.5em 0 1.5em -0.75em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset -1.5em 0 1.5em -0.75em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: inset -1.5em 0 1.5em -0.75em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #4EFFFF;
  color: #000;
}

article {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1500px;
  background: #e3e3e3;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 100%;
}

article h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px 0 30px;
}

article p {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

article a.toggle-nav {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: rgb(255, 139, 139);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #444;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-wrap">

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="push-wrap">

    <article>
      <a href="#" class="toggle-nav"></a>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">

            <h1>Off Screen Navigation</h1>
            <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah !</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>

  </div>

</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't suggest you change the size of your container for responsive reasons, since all elements inside will be affected and you could have many layout issues.

But anyway if you can ensure all it's well coded and will fit you can see you are adding the class `show-nav` wich translates your main container to the right, what you need is change that to modify the `width` instead, using `calc()` :

**Run Snippet on Full Page**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.toggle-nav').click(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('show-nav');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  width: 700px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.site-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.push-wrap {
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: all 1.2s linear;
  width:100%;
}
.show-nav .push-wrap {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: calc(100% - 700px);
  transform: translate(700px, 0);
}
body {
  background: #e3e3e3;
}
a {
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
nav {
  background: #2b343f;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1.5em 0 1.5em -0.75em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset -1.5em 0 1.5em -0.75em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: inset -1.5em 0 1.5em -0.75em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #4EFFFF;
  color: #000;
}
article {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1500px;
  background: #e3e3e3;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 100%;
}
article h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
article p {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
article a.toggle-nav {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: rgb(255, 139, 139);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #444;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-wrap">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="push-wrap">
    <article>
      <a href="#" class="toggle-nav"></a>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Off Screen Navigation</h1>
            <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
              !
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To give you an idea of what is possible take a look at this tympanus example: http://tympanus.net/Development/SidebarTransitions/

I guess your best option would be to do something similar to the scaledown pusher example. That is your best bet is to scale down the current page to keep it visible.

A tip for next time: put your code in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for people to view your example easier next time.

Comment: Thank you Ben.  I thought of that as soon as I hit submit, so I quickly threw this together on Codepen:                                                          [http://codepen.io/midasxl/pen/ZOpmEz](http://codepen.io/midasxl/pen/ZOpmEz)  Hope that helps.

Comment: I was going to suggest codepen as another option but forgot the name :S

Comment: And thanks for the link to the Tympanus examples.  They look very interesting.  Our users still need to be able to interact with the main content when the menu is visible, but these examples may lead me in the right direction.

Comment: Well, all you need to do is not put a covering div over the main content.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have quickly done this in JS fiddle.

Is this the type of effect you are looking for?

https://jsfiddle.net/cmuffinj/1ktLzfb2/

CSS:

```
nav {
width: 700px;
height: 100%;
display: none;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.site-wrap {
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.push-wrap {
border: 1px solid red;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms ease 0;
-moz-transition: all 300ms ease 0;
-o-transition: all 300ms ease 0;
transition: all 300ms ease 0;

-webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
-ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
-o-transform: translate(0, 0);
transform: translate(0, 0);

-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.show-nav .push-wrap {
border: 1px solid green;
transform: translate(700px, 0); 
transform: translate3d(700px, 0, 0);
}

body {
background: #e3e3e3;
}

a {
transition: all 300ms ease;
}

nav {
background: #2b343f;
text-align: center;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset -1.5em 0 1.5em -0.75em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: inset -1.5em 0 1.5em -0.75em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
box-shadow: inset -1.5em 0 1.5em -0.75em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

nav ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none !important;
height: 60px;
line-height: 60px;
font-size: 18px;
color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
background: #4EFFFF;
color: #000;
}

article {
position: relative;
min-height: 1500px;
background: #e3e3e3;
z-index: 9;
width: 100%;
}

article h1 {
text-align: center;
margin: 40px 0 30px;
}

article p {
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 30px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
}

article a.toggle-nav {
position: absolute;
font-size: 25px;
color: rgb(255, 139, 139);
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: #444;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
line-height: 60px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {

    $('.toggle-nav').click(function() {
        $('nav').slideToggle();
    });

});
```